# Manipulating the preview bitmap from camera

Tags: android, graphics, camera

I am trying to create a live Kaleidoscope app like the one found here: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/live-kaleidoscope/32e41ccf-5a25-42ea-84ff-07688f3e6aa5.

For this I ve been able to get the bitmap corresponding to the camera preview. I am trying to create a polygon from triangular paths, and fill the paths with the bitmap after manipulating the bitmap using matrix transformations. I am yet to work on those transformations, however right now I am not even seeing the polygon and the images inside them. I am not getting any errors in my code. When I run the application, I only see the camera running. I am stuck! Please help! Here is my code:

public class Kaleidoscope extends View

{

```
Bitmap imageData;
Canvas canvas1;
int picWidth, picHeight, ang, displayWidth, displayHeight, numOfsides;
float triangleSide, triangleHeight;

public Kaleidoscope(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Kaleidoscope(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void init(Bitmap image, int sides, int w, int h) {

    numOfsides = sides;
    triangleSide = (w - 100) / 2;
    // triangleHeight=(float)Math.tan(Math.PI/3)*triangleSide/2;
    displayWidth = w;
    displayHeight = h;
    imageData = image;
    draw();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas1 = canvas;
}

public void draw() {

    float angle = 360 / numOfsides;
    float totalAngle = 0;
    float centerX = displayWidth / 2;
    float centerY = displayHeight / 2;
    float cornerX = centerX + triangleSide;
    float cornerY = centerY / 2;
    Matrix mat = new Matrix();

    mat.postTranslate(picWidth / 2, 0);

    // Matrix mat2=mat;
    //
    // float concatArray[]={-1,0,0,1,0,0};
    // Matrix concatMat=new Matrix();
    // concatMat.setValues(concatArray);
    // mat2.postConcat(concatMat);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfsides; i++) {

        float verticalDistance = (triangleSide * (float) (Math.sin(Math
                .toRadians(totalAngle))));
        float horizontalDistance = (triangleSide * (float) (Math.cos(Math
                .toRadians(totalAngle))));

        float x = (displayWidth / 2) + horizontalDistance - (picWidth / 2);
        float y = (displayHeight / 2) + verticalDistance - (picHeight / 2);

        Path triangle = new Path();
        triangle.lineTo(cornerX, cornerY);
        triangle.lineTo(x, y);
        triangle.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        cornerX = x;
        cornerY = y;
        totalAngle = totalAngle + angle;
        Bitmap matBitmap;

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            matBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageData, 0, 0,
                    imageData.getWidth(), imageData.getHeight(), mat, true);
        } else {
            matBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageData, 0, 0,
                    imageData.getWidth(), imageData.getHeight(), mat, true);
        }

        BitmapShader fillBMPshader = new BitmapShader(matBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        Paint fill = new Paint();
        fill.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fill.setShader(fillBMPshader);

        canvas1.drawPath(triangle, fill);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to make my own Kaleidoscope class, tried your code and only get crashes. Will you be willing to share an updated class for this view?

Answer (score 0):

first, sorry about my writing of english. (because i'm korean)

If you use camera in android, the class named `preview` will extend `SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.callback`.

Then `mainActivity` calls this class. right?

After `mainActivity` calls the `preview` class, you have to make another class that extends `View` class.

make method named `onDraw` for overriding: `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` and just make sources in this method, like this:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
mPaint.setTextSize(40);
canvas.drawText("X", canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, mPaint);
```

then go back to `mainActivity` and do `addView`.

the name of 'view class' in this source is 'test'.

```
final FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
if (camview == null) {
    camview = new Preview(this);
    frame.addView(camview);
    test = new InvalidateTest(context);
    frame.addView(test, new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

make in a word, just make new class and add this view at the (frame) layout.